# Force browser to redraw an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Is there a way to force the browser to redraw an image with the same source and same image without an HTTP get?

I need to do this because **Chrome** has a rendering bug. When I move a drag-gable element that is on top an image the element leave a white trace.

Comment: Detach, and re-attach it to the DOM? Set its `src` property to `null`, and than back to its original value?

Comment: By "HTML get" you mean "HTTP get" I presume...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do a simple:

```
$("#myimg").hide()
```

then

```
$("#myimg").show()
```

Comment: $('#myImg').hide();
setTimeout(function(){$('#myImg').show();}, 1);

Comment: this work when the dragging stop, but during the dragging it doesn't because the image is just hidden

Answer (score 1):

Updating the `src` attribute of the image (via JavaScript) after the drop might work. (And if the file is in cache, there should be no 'html get'.

Comment: I tried but I am getting an html get with the flashing of the image.

Comment: But a faulty transfer may be the source of the problem so taking the image from cache may not eliminate the problem. Replacing the `src` with the same address but adding a query `?rand=3435436` may help flush the browser cache and pull the image again.

Answer (score 1):

To force a redraw, try calling:

```
$("body").toggleClass("refresh");
```

The class "refresh" doesn't have to be defined, but this usually fixes issues with dom elements not being redrawn or updated when they should.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new image (with the same source) to the document.  Use `position: absolute` to put it over the old mis-rendered image.  That might avoid screen flash/flicker.

This is assuming that the image was downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myImg').hide();
setTimeout(function(){$('#myImg').show();}, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend setting the opacity. The opacity property will force the browser to do a complete redraw of the element without effecting the dragging like so.

```
function startDragFix(ele){
    var originalOpacity = ele.style.opacity, curOpacity = originalOpacity;
    var curID = [0, originalOpacity, ele];
    curID[0] = requestAnimationFrame(function repeatTransparencySwitch(){
        var direction = originalOpacity >= .5 ? -1 : 1;
        if (curOpacity === originalOpacity){
            // 1/64th of a transparency %, barely noticeable, but just enough
            ele.style.opacity = (curOpacity += direction*.015625);
        } else {
            ele.style.opacity = curOpacity = originalOpacity;
        }
        curID[0] = requestAnimationFrame(repeatTransparencySwitch);
    });
} 
function endDragFix(data){
    if (data) {
           data[2].style.opacity = originalOpacity;
           cancelAnimationFrame(data[0]);
    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
var fixID = startDragFix(document.getElementById("foobar"));
setTimeout(function(){
    endDragFix(fixID);
}, 5000);
```